# Why have an inductor between 2 parallel capacitors? (LED driver)

Tags: capacitor, inductor, parallel

This is the driver for an [LED bulb](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/414791/39799). I don't understand why there is an inductor between the 2 capacitors C1 and C2. I understand that C1 and C2 are used to handle [low frequency ripple and the noise](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21686/whats-the-purpose-of-two-capacitors-in-parallel/21695#21695), but what does the 3mH inductor do?

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: Google "pi filter".

Comment: @JohnD Thanks! I lost a lot of time because I didn't had the right term and couldn't find any information!

Comment: Note that, because the inductor and resistor are there, the capacitors are not in fact parallel.

Comment: @Hearth, so what are they if they aren't in serial or in parallel?

Comment: @MagTun What do you mean? They're not in series and they're not in parallel, that's certainly allowed. It would be a boring world if everything had to be one of the two.

Comment: @Hearth, ok but then how to you know which context (series vs parallel) to use to apply Ohm's law to find out the current / resistance / voltage in each "branch"/composant?

Comment: @MagTun Ohm's law doesn't care about the context. If you're talking about circuit transformations, for a situation like this you may need to use the wye-delta transform (or the general form, the star-polygon transform), which is a little bit more complicated than the basic series and parallel transformations people learn at the beginning of EE101. In addition to that, Kirchoff's laws are your friend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! By context, I was talking about this https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-5/correct-use-of-ohms-law . Thanks for the  wye-delta transform and the Kirchoff's laws, I think that was what I was missing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Driving low voltage high current LEDs off an AC line requires a smoothened current pump and then a precision constant current sink to regulate LED heat over a wide range of input Vac.

- The bridge has a low resistance so surge currents into C1 must be low at turn on during the Vac peak, so C1 is small.
- Yet it must have large enough energy capacity to reduce the ripple voltage and thus current in L1.
- L1 must be large enough to feed the current to the LED with minimal DCR for current inductor rating to drive the LED string voltage, Vf, so I(Lmin) > I(led)
- If L is too small it will rapidly decay with a load ESR of ~ 0.5 n/Pd for n LEDs in string total power, Pd

  - current pump decay time to store the energy Ec=1/CV^2 must just exceed DC energy of load
  - yet peak power  for 1/2 cycle AC depends on 50% duty cycle .
- T1 further helps to reduce the slew rise in current but when If is sensed the drain cuts off with hysteresis

  - so you now have a hysteretic buck Pulse duration and frequency modulated step-down constant current sink with a  bit of ripple determined by the %hysteresis.
- You may consider it in the frequency domain as a Pi filter or CLC filter
- The impedance for input and output are high input
- The Zout is low and as LPF ripple attenuation and Q are limited by Requiv. / Zc(f)
- Here C1 does not do much and the LCL filter resonates around 1.8 kHz with high Q when conducting
- When the LED’s are OFF,  it is critically damped with an LED ~ < 15 ohms each) +  Rs for a total of about 100 ohms for 5mm parts
- The 2nd L or T1 is now switching on and off so the PWM and frequency depend on the hysteresis, Vac input and Power output.
- If the freq is 18kHz, the ripple is reduced 40dB
- **It is mostly a 2nd order filter** in this range
- C1 also reduces some radiated EMI voltage noise levels but raises EMI conducted current levels so it is chosen smaller by that selected ratio.
- The open-drain regulates the current to be constant

  - with residual current between on cycles at >10x the Pi filter
  - with the shunt cap across the LEDs depending C value RsC=T

    - **being dt= dV*C/Ic for the hysteretic dV value.**

I hope this reads a bit better.

I suggest you learn the Falastad SImulator and test this out. Beta for the FET can be changed calculated for RdsOn with FET properties. Start with Beta=1 (higher for lower Ron)  e.g. http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html  or [my example](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0Y2CMBOJyWoBwjpNAWA7AgKxoBsYJcMCahJIhEhIOGhApgLRxwBQAbphw4QAJjAY4QwcIhwQZTCQSQ8YWiLwt8eSeD1hIhHgBNRtaSADMYYXDx1LIY2wBmAQwCuAGwAuJs3RiGNa29lZOrp6%20-iIioYHmksKOzu7efqax8QGi4uGpUX4A7qJxmGFZpTI8JSHlDmL14DVVrThwgWVgLZaNdg4kEmHdAE7MHU04JNkQ%20N0AHswEoqT0cI4iaAjMiiAAWgDCAMoAOgDOvGMiiVJJFhCxsAZPL2CWPFfmQRbfD2Kw0FesHeAGMcndroE8rJONsRJARJZcHhiGpYgh7ExnvAeD5xp1hFNhJVZCAuJAKHARNM4IQGJsOo4ONi0OtaTAKKQcI88JgYBE0tFTO0EnQRa0RALCi0iTlxZDmjgwLzZf1mAg6GreABzegKb60P4yZpjQ2KRgKKkYWaqboAJT1sk2jswVP0zEY7oMRhKZrVZCGgRl01ESuYIYV3RK8vMlkGOVG%20LaEzVf1gPDE216sjC2YTUCeciwZEs6zjeAIShIxGtgKLPXjavFqYbGAVecjPAADlZG7n4wq5BAoy6Ohac3RugB7PRDzDo2RKFRqMAIWntSyEBDcgswOeSiDvGfbOdK6iYBFYuvqLGiEBZngzkRFvSWew7q9z3hPphf6wkTUVF6EhIUIFFSyIN1sXgWceCAA)

Comment: Could you consider adding punctuation (espacially commas and points)? It would make it much easier for (some of) us none native english speaker.

Comment: @JonasDaverio  Thanks It was terrible, I see. I must have been feeling ill that day. ;)

Answer (score 4):

C2 handles the low frequency ripple, for power into the LEDs.

The inductor+C1 is to stop RF from the power conversion switching from getting back onto the mains, and making the module fail emission standards.